# using Reflections to access an Enum and use "Enum.TryParse" to compare values

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, enums

I have a class with an Enum, and i need to load that class at runtime using reflections and compare a string value to the enum and evaluate if its a valid enum using Enum.TryParse. any ideas thanks

Comment: Please post your approach and the problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
    // converting enums to strings is easy    
    String WhatDayItIs = DayOfWeek.Monday.ToString();     

    // converting strings to enums is a bit more work    
    DayOfWeek WhatDayItIsDOW;

    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DayOfWeek), WhatDayItIs)) 
        WhatDayItIsDOW = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek),
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this do?

```
    public class myClass
    {
        public enum myEnum
        {
            Item1,
            Item2
        }
    }

    public class otherClass
    {
        public otherClass()
        {
            if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(myClass.myEnum)).Contains("Item1"))
                Console.WriteLine("We have a match!");
        }
    }
```